# Analog of TOEFL for German

Tags: learning, proficiency-test

Could anyone suggest me most actual or appropriate analog of TOEFL (Test of English as a Foreign Language) for German?

Answer (score 7):

TestDaF is what you're looking for.

It's the most appropriate analog of TOEFL since it's accepted by all German universities. And even the test-taking procedure is similar: you will be talking to a computer (and not a human being like in IELTS).

Answer (score 4):

Besides TestDaF, three tests I've heard of:

- Contrary to TestDaF, which is standard even worldwide, [*DSH*](http://www.dsh-germany.com/info/DSH) (Deutsche Sprachprüfung für den Hochschulzugang) varies from university to university. And the name explains what it is.
- The certificates of Goethe-Institut: Universities ask for a C1 or C2 level.
- An option, which I don't know if is valid in Germany, is [ÖSD](http://www.osd.at/default.aspx?SIid=27&LAid=1#frage173) the *Österreichisches Sprachdiplom Deutsch*.

Comment: To be precise, I don't think they (universities) require a C2 level, it would be strongly unfair. I've checked Uni Leipzig and it wants a TestDaF 4 (roughly between and B2 and C1), here you can have a guide about usual requirements: http://www.testdaf.de/teilnehmer/pdf/informationen_en.pdf

Comment: @martina That's right. However, it depends on what you want to study. For sciences, C1 is enough. For *Geistwissenschaft* I think one would need C2 though.

Comment: @c.p.: I strongly doubt that. It's probably reverse.

Comment: @Quandary well, I meant *Naturwissenschaft*; all is published in English. On the other hand, lot is lost if you read, say, Nietzsche in English.